# Tablesorter and search

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a big table and I want to add a search function on it. I used tablesorter to do the columns sortables and also a tutorial to add another column in the beginning for numbering the rows. But Search doesn't work. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.quicksearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered tablesorter">
       <thead>

       </thead>
       <tbody>

       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
         <tr style="display:none;">
             <td colspan="5">
                 No rows match the filter...
             </td>
        </tr>       
       </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div id="pager" class="pager">
        <form>
             <img src="/static/blue/first.png" class="first"/>
             <img src="/static/blue/prev.png" class="prev"/>
             <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
             <img src="/static/blue/next.png" class="next"/>
             <img src="/static/blue/last.png" class="last"/>
             <select class="pagesize">
             <option value="10">10 per page</option>
             <option value="20">20 per page</option>
             <option value="50">50 per page</option>
             </select>
       </form>
    </div>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
    $.tablesorter.addWidget({
    id: "numbering",
    format: function(table) {
        var c = table.config;
        $("tr:visible", table.tBodies[0]).each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(i + 1);
        });
    }
});


    $("table").tablesorter({widgets: ['numbering'],sortInitialOrder: 'desc', sortList: [[2,1]],headers: {0: {sorter: false}}})
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});

    $("#myTable tbody tr").quicksearch({
            labelText: 'Search: ',
            attached: '#myTable',
            position: 'before',
            delay: 100,
            loaderText: 'Loading...',
            onAfter: function() {
                if ($("#myTable tbody tr:visible").length != 0) {
                    $("#myTable").trigger("update");
                    $("#myTable").trigger("appendCache");
                    $("#myTable tfoot tr").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#myTable tfoot tr").show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

I don't see any error. Just the search function doesn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like quicksearch is being attached to `#table` and not `#myTable` which is the ID of the table in the HTML you shared.

Comment: Damn...Always like this :P I search for a serious error and I forgot the misspelling errors. Thank you a lot.

Comment: The search now is there but it doesn't load anything. :(

Comment: Might I be so bold as to suggest you try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)... here is a [demo of it working with quicksearch](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ZFZNF/16/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [datatables.js/](http://datatables.net/) a try.  It is a jQuery plugin that will do what you are trying to build and is very simple to implement.

The code to implement it (which has paging, searching, column sorting, etc as defaults) is this.

```
  $('#example').dataTable();
```

Comment: Will I have the addwidget feature to add a numbering column for rows?

Comment: There are many working examples that you can look at here [link](http://datatables.net/examples/).   Everything from the basics to get up and running to interactive tables.  Take a look at some of the examples to see just want the plugin offers

Comment: This is the demo you mean: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/counter_column.html